# When there is a mongod that already has data, data is not visible when configuring a shard

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, sharding

When there is a mongod that already has data, the data is not visible when configuring the shard
In detail
Two mongods have a collection with the same name and the following data is stored
Info(A,B mongod)

```
DB : db_test
Collection : test_log
```

A mongod

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f44cfa372c25aeff48e66d3"), "skey" : 100, "data" : 1 }
```

B mongod

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f44cf731eadcef49cd93e7b"), "skey" : 200, "data" : 2 }
```

In Mongos, I did the following command

```
mongos> sh.addShard("A.MASTER:21011")
    { "shardAdded" : "shard0000", "ok" : 1 }
    
    mongos> sh.addShard("B.SLAVE1:21011")
    { "shardAdded" : "shard0001", "ok" : 1 }
    
    mongos> sh.addShardTag("shard0000", "master")
    WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
    mongos> sh.addShardTag("shard0001", "slave_1")
    WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
    
    mongos> sh.enableSharding("db_test")
    { "ok" : 1 }
    
    mongos> sh.shardCollection("db_test.test_log", {skey:1})
    { "collectionsharded" : "db_test.test_log", "ok" : 1 }

    mongos> sh.addTagRange("db_test.test_log", {skey:100}, {skey:199},  "master")
    WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 1,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "_id" : {
            "ns" : "db_test.test_log",
            "min" : {
                "skey" : 100
            }
        }
    })
    mongos> sh.addTagRange("db_test.test_log", {skey:200}, {skey:299},  "slave_1")
    WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 1,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "_id" : {
            "ns" : "db_test.test_log",
            "min" : {
                "skey" : 200
            }
        }
    })
```

And I looked up data in mongos ('find, aggregate ..' command was executed)
result

```
mongos> db.test_log.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f44cfa372c25aeff48e66d3"), "skey" : 100, "data" : 1 }
```

before sharding, I executed Command (create index (to use shardkey))

```
mongos> db.test_log.createIndex({ "skey": 1 });
{
    "raw" : {
        "A.MASTER:21011" : {
            "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
            "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
            "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
            "ok" : 1
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I wonder what's the problem
When creating an index in mongos, I am also curious about the part allocated only to A.master.
Please..

Answer (score 2):

The collection data should all reside on 1 shard before the collection is sharded.

When you run `shardCollection` any initial chunks are created on the database's primary shard.

Additional chunks are created by splitting an already existing chunk.

When the balancer moves a chunk from one shard to another, it first deletes the document range covered by that chunk from the target collection.

When querying via mongos, the router checks with the config servers to find out which shards hold chunks that might be needed for the query, and directs the query to only those shards.

Tags and tag ranges are consulted by the balancer to determine where to move chunks.  These are not consulted by the mongos routers.

So what happened in your scenario is you had a database with a collection that existed on more than one mongod node,  each with an index on `{skey: 1}`

You then created a sharded cluster by adding both of those mongod nodes as individual shards.

At this point, the config servers would not have had any information about the database or the collection.

When you ran `enableSharding`, the config servers created a config document for the database, and assigned one of the shards to be the database's primary shard.
At this point any query for any unsharded collection in that database would be handled by the primary shard.

When you ran `shardCollection`, the config servers created a document for the collection that identifies the shard key.  It also created a single chunk from MinKey to MaxKey, identified as residing on the database's primary shard.

Your subsequent query for the data was serviced by the mongos, which consulted the chunk list for the collection, finding that there was only 1 chunk. It then forwarded that request to the owning shard, which returned the data it had. The other shard would have never been consulted.

You can check how the chunks are distributed by running `sh.status(true)`.

At this point, splitting the existing chunk and letting it balance will not help, because the range will be cleared before moving the chunk. This means any documents on the other shard will be deleted before the empty chunk is moved.

There is no simple method to take 2 separate replica sets that already contain data and join them together in a sharded cluster. In that scenario, the simplest approach would be to mongodump the data from one replica set, create a sharded cluster with the other, after enabling sharding on all databses, then add the remaining replica set as a second shard, and then mongorestore the remaining data.

For a single replica set that contains data, there is a documented procedure to [Convert a Replica Set to a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/#convert-a-replica-set-to-a-sharded-cluster)